# save edittext value after data entry

Tags: android, android-edittext

After a check box is checked i create an EditText view and save the checked value.

```
if (checked){
        //add to array
        checkIn.add(boxName);
        mLayout.addView(createNewEditText(boxNumber),count+1);
        //set focus and open keyboard
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(100+ Integer.parseInt(boxNumber));
        editText.requestFocus();
    }else {
        //remove from array
        checkIn.remove(boxName);
        int intTextId = Integer.parseInt(boxNumber);
        mLayout.removeView(findViewById(100+intTextId));
    }
```

Next the user may enter data into the EditText.
I want to save the value after data is entered.

I have searched the googles and have not found anything.

Any ideas

Comment: you are dynamically creating a edit text, or are you showing it when a checkbox is checked? how many edit texts are being shown at once? seems like a better idea to just hide the edit text onCreate, and then show it when the box is checked.

Comment: is there any save button or you want to save the data after user has paused typing for a defined period of time

Comment: I am dynamically creating the edit text. The list can be 30 + check boxes. Every checked check box has an edit text added. Removed when unchecked.

Comment: there is a save button for all the data on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextChangedListener:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
      {
        //do something with your text
      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
   });
}
```

Comment: When is afterTextChanged and onTextChanged triggered?